# Onelogin - Is there a way to not use password to generate a saml assertion?

Tags: amazon-web-services, saml-2.0, onelogin

https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/saml-assertions/generate-saml-assertion

I'm generating a SAML assertion to use with AWS assumerolewithSAML, to generate temporary access keys and have this working, but I'd prefer to not have to pass a password...

I understand passing the password is over https and reasonably secure, but was thinking about having a process to do this on a schedule so that people requiring an AWS access key could run a script to refresh their keys since AWS only allows max 1 hour lifetime of temporary credentials.  I don't want this script to know/memorize user passwords etc.

Not sure if we could use some other method or even a salted password?  Any other secure thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to SO, but I can tell you didn't read the "How do I ask a Question" section on this site before making your first post. You also didn't even bother to take the 2-minute site tour.  It doesn't appear that you did much, if any, Internet research into this question. Please review stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting again.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being username/password is it, since this call effectively lets you impersonate a user.

A) Please complain to AWS - I think the one hour time limit is far to low and they allow for SAML assertions to ask for longer sessions of other types (just not access keys).

B) Consider building a web service with it's own (longer) session/token management. You could then cache and re-use the users' credentials to generate fresh tokens

**Update**
AWS now allows for much longer-lived access tokens, and this should mitigate the issue.

Comment: TBH I consider this suboptimal and even less secure:

 - type the password constantly increases risk of leaks.
 
 - cache the password also risks leaks

 - In general, the least time you handle the password, the better

Onelogin could offer instead a session token with a TTL that would allow to request a SAML Assertion, but always verifying with a MFA code. 

That way, the client software does not cache the password, but the token. the cached token has a expiration date. The impersonation risk can be removed by only allowing is mitigated by always asking for the MFA token.

Comment: AWS now allows for much longer session lengths with their supplied access token and this should mitigate the issue.